Free PDF of Moshe Zacutto Shorshei Shemot In English Online?
BH
Does anyone know a free PDF of the Book Shorshei HaShemot by Moshe Zaccuto in English?

I don't believe there's an English translation at all, let alone on available online for free.

If you'd like to learn this sefer, this place teaches it in English: https://kabbalahinstitute.com/index.php/our-club/

One of the five volumes is available in English for free download at scribd.com. Volume 2 is available at Shorshei HaShemot by Moshe Zaccuto, Volume 2
The English translation is rather mysterious.  No library seems to own it, and no bookseller seems to have it.
